# Cassandra Upgrade 2.1 to 3.11

Tags: upgrade, cassandra

I  have a multi(two) DC Apache cassandra cluster with active replication. DC1 is primary(production) and DC2 is DR.
I  plan to upgrade from  2.1 to 3.11. What is the best way to achieve the upgrade without downtime in the production?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

While the versions might be different, the steps found here can mostly be followed.

[Upgrade steps for Cassandra 3 -> 4](https://www.datastax.com/learn/whats-new-for-cassandra-4/migrating-cassandra-4x)

First, I would start by ensuring that a complete repair has successfully run on the cluster.

Second, I would reach out to the application team(s), and make sure that they are using a [version of the driver that can connect to both Cassandra 2 and Cassandra 3](https://docs.datastax.com/en/driver-matrix/docs/java-drivers.html).  I'd also (just for the duration of the upgrade) have them *force* a [CQL binary protocol](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.7/manual/native_protocol/#native-protocol) connection version of **v3**. Otherwise, the driver will negotiate to the highest possible version in the cluster, and then fail to reconnect to the old nodes during the upgrade process; possibly leading to application downtime.

Then these steps can be taken, one node at a time:

- Flush memtables to disk (`nodetool drain`)
- Shut down the node
- Make sure the correct Java version is installed (Java 8 for Cassandra 3.x)
- Install the new version of Cassandra
- Configure the new yaml file (don't just copy the old one in, they *do* change)
- Configure the new version to point to the old data files
- Start the node and check `system.log` for errors

Once the entire cluster has been upgraded, run `nodetool upgradesstables` on one node at a time.  Cassandra 3 can read Cassanra 2.1's data files, but not the other way around.

Note that your users are going to be converted to "roles," as Cassandra 3 uses a RBAC security model (Cassandra 2.1 does not).  Cassandra 3 will do this conversion for you, and you can delete the original user-based tables:

- system_auth.users
- system_auth.credentials
- system_auth.permissions

Note, the upgrade process can be reversed (back to Cassandra 2.1) at any time, until either of two actions have been taken:

- Deleting the legacy user-based tables.
- Running `nodetool upgradesstables`.

Once either of those tasks have been completed, there's no going back.  At least not easily.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You also have another option to build the destination/target cluster on the desired version (recommended to use [the latest `4.1.x` version](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/download.html) which is `4.1.3` as of this writing) directly and use [**Zero Downtime Migration (ZDM)**](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/migrate/introduction.html#_supported_releases) utility if you're on a supported `Apache Cassandra 2.1.6+` version for your source/origin cluster.

It is also critical that you understand the overall upgrade path by referencing the link shared earlier in the prior answer or [this documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/luna-cassandra/docs/guides/upgrade/overview.html).